# 403 forbidden on recaptcha only when deployed

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I've got a 403 - forbidden while send a key to recaptcha v2 from google.
Locally, at the 127.0.0.1 it works.
But when published at IIS, the problem occurs.
The Elmah log reports Forbidden 403 and when I comment the request line and republish, my app works.

Im trying to send with a WebClient, sending the key with GET params.

Again:
Locally it works ok, but when published at my IIS instance, I receive 403 error.

It can be a server infrastructure/proxy/firewall problem?

Comment: Have you got the correct domains for where you publish setup in the reCaptcha settings?

Comment: The issue is with the TLS/SSL TCP connection failing which could be many different things.. You could not have a route to the server, you  do not have the credentials, the port number is blocked, using wrong version of TLS/SSL, the encryption options in TLS/SSL are not correct (including key size and padding), the wrong certificate (or expired certificate).